# homebrew libgfortran

Tags: homebrew, gcc

My Python app is using scipy which apparently needs libgfortran. After a recent brew update/upgrade, my Python app fails to run due to a libgfortran dependency issue:

```
dlopen(<snip>/scipy-0.14.0-py2.7-macosx-10.10-intel.egg/scipy/linalg/_fblas.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/gcc/4.9/libgfortran.3.dylib
```

I have gcc 4.9 installed, but there is no fortran library or anything matching /usr/local/lib/gcc/4.9/*fort*. There are tons of other libs in /usr/local/lib/gcc/4.9/

I successfully installed gcc 4.9 through homebrew, however I could not get gfortran installed:

```
➜  ~  brew install gfortran
Error: No available formula for gfortran 
GNU Fortran is now provided as part of GCC, and can be installed with:
  brew install gcc
➜  ~  brew install gcc     
Warning: gcc-5.1.0 already installed
➜  ~  brew install homebrew/versions/gcc49
Warning: homebrew/versions/gcc49-4.9.2_1 already installed
➜  ~  brew install homebrew/versions/gcc49 gfortran
Error: No available formula for gfortran 
GNU Fortran is now provided as part of GCC, and can be installed with:
  brew install gcc
➜  ~  brew install gcc gfortran      
Error: No available formula for gfortran 
GNU Fortran is now provided as part of GCC, and can be installed with:
  brew install gcc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be installed and linked from the gcc formula:

```
~ » readlink `which gfortran`                                                                                      
../Cellar/gcc/5.1.0/bin/gfortran
```